# From numpy to sparse.coo_matrix works. From pandas DataFrame to np array to sparse.coo_matrix doesn't work: IndexError

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

**Case 1:** From numpy array to coo_matrix:

```
    ar = np.array([['user1', 'product1'], ['user2', 'product2'], ['user3', 'product3'], ['user1', 'product4'],['user4','product5'],['user4','product1']])
    ar

> array([['user1', 'product1'],
>        ['user2', 'product2'],
>        ['user3', 'product3'],
>        ['user1', 'product4'],
>        ['user4', 'product5'],
>        ['user4', 'product1']], dtype='|S8')
```

then create the coo_matrix:

```
rows, r_pos = np.unique(ar[:,0], return_inverse=True)
cols, c_pos = np.unique(ar[:,1], return_inverse=True)
s = sparse.coo_matrix((np.ones(r_pos.shape,int), (r_pos, c_pos)))
print s
```

Gives:

```
  (0, 0)    1
  (1, 1)    1
  (2, 2)    1
  (0, 3)    1
  (3, 4)    1
  (3, 0)    1
```

**Case 2:** Same elements of the array but to DataFrame and then to sparse Matrix ( This case is the one that I need to run correctly because initially I have the data in a DataFrame, not as a numpy array).

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(ar, columns = ['user_id','product_id'])
ar1 = np.array(df1.to_records(index=False))
ar1
```

Gives:

```
array([('user1', 'product1'), ('user2', 'product2'),
       ('user3', 'product3'), ('user1', 'product4'),
       ('user4', 'product5'), ('user4', 'product1')],
      dtype=(numpy.record, [(u'user_id', 'O'), (u'product_id', 'O')]))
```

Create the coo_matrix:

```
rows, r_pos = np.unique(ar1[:,0], return_inverse=True)
cols, c_pos = np.unique(ar1[:,1], return_inverse=True)
s = sparse.coo_matrix((np.ones(r_pos.shape,int), (r_pos, c_pos)))
print s
```

Output:

```
IndexErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-211-75a151d3e431> in <module>()
----> 1 rows, r_pos = np.unique(ar1[:,0], return_inverse=True)
      2 cols, c_pos = np.unique(ar1[:,1], return_inverse=True)
      3 s = sparse.coo_matrix((np.ones(r_pos.shape,int), (r_pos, c_pos)))
      4 print s

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Why do I get this IndexError? The only difference between the 2 cases is in **dtype** but I didn't understand how to change it so it runs for **case 2**.

Comment: index the fields of `ar1` by field name, not column number.  Review the use of structured arrays. `ar1['user_id']`

Comment: do you mean using `df1.to_records()` instead of setting `index=False`?

Comment: No in the problem line use the correct indexing method for the shape and dtype of `ar1`

Comment: can you write it as an answer not a comment? I corrected it and it works but I didn't understand why it should be indexed by field name, not column number (even though I took a look at structured arrays in numpy documentation.

Comment: Check the shape.  It isn't a 2d array.